# Augmented Reality Application in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, augmented-reality

I am trying to create an ios application using which we can convert a real life object e.g Sofa, Table as 3D objects using IPhone's camera. These 3D object info can be saved in the database and can be displayed as Augumented reality objects when the IPhone camera is pointed at some other part of the room.

I have searched the internet but could'nt find any info on where to get started to convert real life objects to 3D objects for viewing as augumented reality objects.

Answer (score 0):

check below link where you found SDK and also sample code for implement AR

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS

Answer (score 0):

I think any way you go with this it's going to be huge task. However I've had good results with similar goals using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org).

It has an iOS SDK, but is written in C++. Unfortunately I don't think there's anything available that will allow you to achieve this using pure Obj-C or Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through following links

1. https://www.qualcomm.com/products/vuforia
2. http://www.t-immersion.com/ar-key-words/augmented-reality-sdk#
3. http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/
4. https://www.layar.com